# Setting Types for Array of Objects in TypeScript gives error

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, constructor, instantiation

I have these 2 interfaces

```
interface CartPackageData {
   packageId: number;
   packageName: string;
   packagePrice: number;
   quantity: number;
}

interface Cart extends Array<CartPackageData>{
   packages?: CartPackageData[];
   products?: CartPackageData[];
   fines?: Array<any>;
}

export Class MyClass {
   cart: Cart = [];
   constructor() {

// this works;
      this.cart.packages = [];
      this.cart.products = [];
      this.cart.fines = [];

//this one doesnt work
      this.cart = {
         packages: [],
         products: [],
         fines: []
      };
}
```

The second example says `Error:(73, 7) TS2322: Type '{ packages: undefined[]; products: undefined[]; fines: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Cart'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type '{ packages: undefined[]; products: undefined[]; fines: undefined[]; }'.`

Why does the first way work but the second fails?

Also, does this even make sense the way I set the interfaces up?

The data will look like this the second example when its implemented.

Comment: If the data will look like the second example then `Cart` is not an array at all.  Get rid of `extends Array<CartPackageData>` and if you're going to initialize `MyClass.cart` then initialize it properly, since it should not be `[]`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, its not an array. I changed the structure around and missed that. Now it works. Is it better to initialize the cart property in the class instance, or in the constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the class instance"?

Comment: I mean, to initialize it as a member like this Class { member: string = 'intial value' } as opposed to in the constructor.

Comment: I don't think one is necessarily better than the other; they have the same effect.  I tend to prefer the member initialization, but I think you should do whichever one suits you.

Comment: Great, thanks. PS are you familiar with Angular2+? My next question is, should I initialize data inside the typescript constructor/member, or inside of Angular's onNgInit() lifecycle hook?

Comment: Sorry, not an Angular expert.

Comment: K thx no problem